# Neo4j Client: Can we throw an exception if there are already maxium number of relationship reached?

Tags: constraints, relationship, neo4jclient

If I have a one to many relationship like 1 Vehicle has 1 to 4 wheels, if someone try to call

graphClient.Create(wheel, new VehicleHasWheel(vehicle.Reference));

can we expect the graphClient to throw an exception so we don't have 5 wheels on a car?

we can define the maxium number to 4 for relationship CarHasWheel.

Right now if i have to check the constrain I need to manaully query the database to get the existing wheels then decide whether i should create another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neo4j does not provide these types of constraints in the box, as it doesn't have a way to specify schema like that.

You could achieve a similar solution by doing your mutations via Cypher queries though:

```
START ...
WHERE ...
CREATE ...
```

That integrates your two queries (decide, then mutate) into one.

To know if something was created or not, return it:

```
START ...
WHERE ...
CREATE ...
RETURN ...
```